# AJAX - form submit, same page, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**EDIT: I have changed the AJAX code to what I am now using and I have also included JQuery in my code**

I've read up on as much AJAX as I can and I am flat out failing!

My HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="match_details.php" method="post" id="match_details">
....
<button type="submit" form="match_details" name="match_details" class="w3-button w3-block w3-mam w3-section" title="Update Match Postcode">Update</button>
            </form>
```

From Stack I've managed to get this AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('button[type=submit]').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "match_details.php",
            data: $("#match_details").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I've tried changing it from button to input and back again but nothing seems to change. The form still submits but it ignores the AJAX and the page refreshes.

Comment: Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: Thank you I have tried this but it didn't make any difference :(

Comment: That's just one problem. The other is `$("myform")`

Comment: I have changed that too but still no joy I'm afraid

Comment: Are you running your code on an actual web server, or just locally on your PC?

Comment: Webserver it's a live site

Comment: And when you press F12 and open the browser's dev tools, you see no errors in the console? How about the network tab?

Comment: Don't know how I missed that I didn't see the error before! It's saying the very first $ in the code is undefined

Comment: Do you have jQuery included in your code?

Comment: Ug. You're not including jQuery.

Comment: HA! I had no idea that was a thing. How would I include JQuery?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Include jQuery like you'd include any JavaScript file

Comment: All now works!! Thank you so much you are both amazing people I wish I could credit both but accepted Adams answer purely as it is the exact code I'm now using. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the JS from submitting the form, and you're using the wrong form ID. Also, judging by the comments, you need to include jquery.

In the head of your HTML file, between `<head>` and `</head>` or just before the closing `</body>` tag, you can use the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The following code may help you (though it's advised to not query the same page as your ajax request emits from):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('button[type=submit]').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "match_details.php",
            data: $("#match_details").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried the code and it didn't work unfortunately, neither did the suggestions above so I'm obviously getting something wrong somewhere on my end.

Comment: Can you open up the Console Log and output any errors?

Comment: Can't find any errors at all. This is all very strange!

Comment: Next step then, when you make the ajax request to the "match_details.php" page, do you have anything listening to see if the form has been submitted?

Comment: Yes and I can see the form has been submitted

Comment: Regarding the comments above, once you include jQuery in your code, give this another attempt and let me know ;)

Comment: Sorry can I also ask if I wanted to output a success message where that would fit in with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152666/discussion-between-adam-a-and-james-v).